# Deployong Django App to Heroku but Heroku pip install can't find module versions matching the requirement.txt

Tags: python, django, heroku

So, I have been trying to deploy my Django app to heroku, but Heroku is trying to pip install older versions of the module that are listed in the requirements.txt

i.e. Heroku is trying to install anaconda-client==1.2.2 but we got anaconda-client==1.7.2 when we do a pip install locally.

Django version == 2.1.4
Python version == 3.7.0

[screen capture of Heroku deployment error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTluK.png)

I've just started to learn python and django for about a month now.. really appreciate any help given. Many appreciate much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create runtime.txt on your  root directory  and add python- 3.7.0 to it